# How to change effects in Cycle 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-cycle2, setattribute

I'm using cycle2 plugin for my website to change images in background. I need to change effect from tileBlind to scrollVert by clicking on button. This is what i created, but it's not working at all.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-timeout=5000
        data-cycle-fx="tileBlind" //here i need change it to data-cycle-fx="scrollVert"
        id = "sli">
        <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="background1">
        <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="background2">
        <img src="img/bg3.jpg" alt="background3">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1()" id="button1">click</button>
```

js:

```
function fun1(){
    var slide = document.getElementById('sli');
    var slide_data = slide.getAttribute('data-cycle-fx');
    slide.setAttribute("data-cycle-fx","scrollVert");
}
```

I'm relatively new in programming, so i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Setting attribute after the plugin is initialized will not work. Set the attribute and try `$(selector).cycle("destroy")`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this realy helped. Not with the `$(selector).cycle("destroy")`, but `$(selector).cycle("stop")` and then `$(selector).cycle("reinit")` with setAttribute. Thanks, you are awesome!